# Modify the django test to pass the django-otp login

Tags: python, django

I am using `django-otp`. Here is the web view

[image]

here is my `urls.py`

```
 path('user_login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name="user_login.html",
                                          authentication_form=SimpleOTPAuthenticationForm, redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='user_login')
```

Here is my .html

```
        <form method="POST" class="form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form %}
            {% buttons %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            {% endbuttons %}
        </form>
```

Here is my forms.py

```
from django_otp.forms import OTPAuthenticationForm
from django import forms


class SimpleOTPAuthenticationForm(OTPAuthenticationForm):
    otp_device = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    otp_challenge = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

The models.py file is

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class ProjectUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Here is the current test I have for username and password

```
class FormTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = {
            'username': 'testuser',
            'password': 'secret'}
        ProjectUser.objects.create_user(**self.credentials)

    def test_user_password_otp_true(self):
        response = self.client.post('/user_login/', self.credentials, follow=True)
        self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_active)
```

How can I change the test to pass the OTP along with the username and password?

[Here is the link to the docs](https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

check line number 60 in this code -> [Here is a link to a test they use](https://bitbucket.org/psagers/django-otp/src/762774ec96b44718659737696ec4a074173ffb83/django-otp/django_otp/tests.py?fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Was there any answer to this? I'm also attempting to run tests with `django-otp` and am receiving 302s after using `client.force_login()` from `django.tests`.

Comment: I'm likewise stuck at the same issue, getting a 403 back when I try to test a view modified by `@otp_required`