# Create authenticated user for django tests

Tags: python, django

The reason I am asking is I have the fields `username`,`password` and `otp_token`. The `otp_token` is challenging to create, therefore I was wondering if there is a way create an authenticated user at the beginning of the test file to carry out the rest of the django tests as an authenticated user?

For example, how to pass a logged in user to the following

```
def some_test(self):
    login = self.client.login(username='testUser', password='testPassword')

    response = self.client.get(reverse('page1:conent1'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55830515/test-user-login-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how are you generating that token, but I think you can use some dummy data in test

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

def setUp(self):
    self.user = User.objects.create(username='<USERNAME>',
                                    email='<EMAIL>', otp_token='<YOUR_VALUE>')
    self.user.set_password(<PASSWORD>)
    self.user.save()
    self.client = Client()

def some_test(self):
    login = self.client.login(username='<USERNAME>', password='<PASSWORD>')
...
```

Comment: unfortunately this will not work as `otp_token` is not part of the User model, it has to be created after the user has been created, if it is no hassle, can you please check the related question ?

Comment: I found that [test](https://github.com/lins05/django-otp/blob/master/test/custom_user/testproj/app/tests.py). I'll take a closer look and will try to replicate a test